# Django dumpdata into docker

Tags: python, django, docker

I have a docker container where is running a django app.
I'm trying to backup my database using cron.
The django app is located in /usr/src/app.

This is my crontab file:`*/1 * * * * cd  /usr/src/app  &&  python manage.py dumpdata>dump.json`

The issue is that the dump.json file is created but nothing is in it.
I tried to run directly python manage.py dumpdata>dump.json bash in my container and it actually works (dump.json is filled with my db content).

Could you help me please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it didn't work is because your command is not referring to your docker container.
To backup your django database from docker container to your local machine you can use:

```
docker exec -it <your_django_container_name> bash python manage.py dumpdata > /path/to/save/dump.json
```

So if you want to do it with crontab just use this in your crontab file:

```
*/1 * * * * docker exec -it <your_django_container_name> bash python manage.py dumpdata > /path/to/save/dump.json
```

To see your container name you can run `docker ps`.

Comment: `docker exec -it <your_django_container_name> bash python manage.py dumpdata > /path/to/save/dump.json` does this work for you ?

Comment: I get this error `sh: 0: cannot open python: No such file`